# $.ajax wait for completion without hanging the UI

Tags: javascript, ajax

Let's say for example, I have the following javascript function that returns a boolean:

```
function CallWebServiceToUpdateSessionUser(target, user)
{
    var dataText = { "jsonUser": JSON.stringify(user) };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: target,
        data: JSON.stringify(dataText),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response)
        {
            return true;
        },
        failure: function (msg)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

and the target function on the server that is being called could take up to... 15 seconds to respond.

How do I guarantee that this function **will not exit** until after the server call has been completed? Or, how can I guarantee that who ever is calling this function will get a true/false and not an undefined?

*NOTE:*
I've seen people use async: false but that hangs the UI which I do not want.

Comment: .ajax() is asynchronous by default and will not hang the browser unless you set async to false. What does debugging with the console show you? By the way, you seem to contradict your self by asking to not let the function exit until the call has completed, but then you say you don't want to wait. Which one is it?

Comment: You want to get the browser stuck until the server responds, without hanging the UI. It's a contradiction.
While the browser is stuck in your function, it can't process anything else.

Comment: Why do you not want the function to exit? That is exactly what you want to happen in order to free up the UI thread once more. You should just popup a "loading" message and then resume the work once the response is received from the server. Possibly allowing the user to cancel the response (or at least ignore the result).

Comment: So how would I let the UI continue but guarantee that a true or false will be returned from this function and not an undefined?

Comment: @Miles, you want your function to be synchronous and wait up to 15 seconds before returning, but you don't want your UI to hang during that time. These two requirements are mutually exclusive, you'll have to choose one.

Comment: @Frederic: man that sucks. I come from a .Net background and you can easily tell the message pump to continue and do anything else it needs to do while waiting for anything to complete. I was hoping there might be something available in javascript.

Comment: @Miles, Javascript is single-threaded, that's why we're using continuations and callbacks instead of the patterns you're familiar with. Note in passing that C# 5.0 arguably encourages the use of continuations with its `async`/`await` pattern, so the two models might become more similar in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.  You need to do an AJAX request with `async: true` to your parameters. You will then need to edit your code so the code that executes after a `successful` request is inside the `successful` block.

Comment: So the code that is in the example will exit with undefined because it didn't wait for the server side function to return. I have to receive the value from the server to continue

Comment: If you are wanting to use asynch, then you are approaching this the wrong way. You need to figure out another way of setting the variable. One possible approach is to put ALL code after the function call inside the success block. Currently there is no way you can have the code function the way you want with async.